# How to show order list in alphabatic order dynamically?

Tags: php, css, mysql, codeigniter

code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="line-height: 1.7;">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('cm_options');
            $where = "qid = '$qid'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            $res = $sql->result_array();
            foreach($res as $rows)
            {
                $option = $rows['q_option']; 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <ol type="A">
                <td width="5%">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><input type="radio" name="radio_btn"></a></li>
                </td>
            </ol>
            <td width="99%"><?php echo $option; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this code I have created objective type question form where option are display perfectly. Now, I want to show all option in alphabet order like A,B,C,D but now, It display dots instead of A,B,C,D. So, How can I display my option in alphabetically order ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I don't quite understand the `It display dots instead of A,B,C,D` mind sharing that part of the generated HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished in CSS with the `list-style-type` of `upper-alpha` on the list element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

You should also be aware that the only valid direct descendent of an `<ol>` (or `<ul>` for that matter) is `<li>`, so what you have going on with your table mingled in there is not good markup.

**For example:**

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Answer 1</li>
  <li>Answer 2</li>
  <li>Answer 3</li>
</ol>
```

You also need to make sure your opening and closing ordered list tags are outside your foreach loop or you'll end up with a new list each iteration of the loop and all items will have 'A' because technically you'll have a bunch of lists with a single item each.

```
<ol>
<?php foreach($res as $rows) {   ?>
    <li>...</li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: after using css it display all list with A,A,A,A,A. I have created list Dynamically buddy.

Comment: that's because you're creating a new `<ol>` with one item inside each iteration of your loop. The `<ol></ol>` tags have to go outside the loop.  Only the `<li>` should be inside the loop.

Comment: @omkara I've edited the answer to address your other issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the order by (also changed the `$this->db->where()` to avoid sql injection):

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="line-height: 1.7;">
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('cm_options');
            $this->db->where('qid', $qid);
            $this->db->order_by('q_option', 'ASC');
            $sql = $this->db->get();
            //echo $this->db->last_query();
            $res = $sql->result_array();
            foreach($res as $rows)
            {
                $option = $rows['q_option']; 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <ol type="A">
                <td width="5%">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><input type="radio" name="radio_btn"></a></li>
                </td>
            </ol>
            <td width="99%"><?php echo $option; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should probably put the `order_by` on `q_option`

Comment: What have  you change? @claudio

Comment: added an order by on the query to order by 'q_option' field